# Проверка окон win api

Tags: c++, winapi

Создал функцию, которая создает дополнительные окна в win api. Только одна проблемка, окно регистрируется и создается по нажатию кнопки, и последующие нажатия по новой регистрируют класс. Как создать условие чтобы если класс этого окна уже зарегистрирован, то не надо его регистрировать по новой ?

Comment: Проще всего будет регистрировать класс в самом начале, а по нажатию - создавать только окно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то желаемое поведение заключается в наличии не более одного открытого окна какого-то класса. Предлагаю пару вариантов для этой задачи.

**Способ 1.** Объявить указатель на объект этого окна, присвоить `nullptr`. Затем, при создании объекта сначала проверять эту переменную — если она равно `nullptr`, то создавать окно и сохранять объект в указателе; иначе ничего не делать.

Вероятно, при закрытии того окна нужно этот указатель будет снова ставить на нуль. Для этого нужно будет тому классу добавить обратную связь в деструкторе: указатель на объект, его породивший, и там уже вызывать метод для очистки первого указателя.

**Способ 2,** попроще. В классе дополнительного окна добавить приватную статическую целочисленную переменную — счётчик количества открытых окон. В конструкторе прибавлять единицу, в деструктор убавлять. А также, публичный статический метод, возвращающий это значение, чтобы его опять же проверять на равенство нулю перед созданием нового объекта.